# What "type" of engine does a Ford Fiesta, 2008, style climate D, 1.4 TDCi have?

Tags: engine, ford, car, fiesta

a mechanic asked me this and I didn't know the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "what type" ... and if the mechanic doesn't know, it's time for a new mechanic. Or was he testing you?

Comment: Do you want the engine code?

Comment: He simply asked what type and said if HDi, its bad. Maybe the engine code would tell me but don't know where on engine to find it

Comment: He needs an ODBII scanner which is an essential tool for success.  IMO, get a new mechanic.  they should know these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking for, but your car has this engine: [Ford DLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_DLD_engine).  It is a inline, 4 cylinder Diesel engine with a turbocharger, but it most likely doesn't have an intercooler.  The 1.4 part is the "displacement" of the engine, and it is basically the "size" of the engine.

This model engine is referred to as "DV4 TD" or "DLD-414".